# WebHook access is possible in Standard edition of BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

We want to integrate our ERP system with BigCommerce for that we plan to buy Standard edition.
But we have following queries:
1) WebHook feature is available in Standard edition?
2) API access? any limit in no of calls?
3) Can this edition allow to do customization based on our requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks are available on all plans. You have a rate limit on API requests per hour, but no API limitations.